# How to import multi-line json to mongodb collection?

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm trying to import documents into a mongodb collection from a json file.
The json is formatted like so:

```
    {"key1-1": "val1-1", "key2-1": "val2-1"}
    {"key1-2": "val1-2", "key2-2": "val2-2"}
    {"key1-3": "val1-3", "key2-3": "val2-3"}
```

I've tried using mongoimport command:

```
    mongoimport --db "test" --collection "inventory" --type json --file "test_files/meta_Video_Games.json" --jsonArray
```

but I got this error:

```
    [js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14
```

which I get because I'm supposed to pass an array of json instead a multi-line json objects file.

Is there a way to import directly via mongo shell?

Comment: The JSON file is okay. I'm able to import something like that using `mongoimport` cli tool. However, I think you are missing an `=` in-between key-value pairs of your command, you can try this: `mongoimport --db="test" --collection="inventory" --type=json --file="test_files/meta_Video_Games.json"`

Comment: I tried using the command I wrote above **outsite** the mongo shell, just from command line (linux terminal) and it worked smoothly. I tried your fix but I still get the same syntax error.

Comment: I did not notice you said you needed to import directly via the mongo shell, the answer is NO, you can't do that. It is also stated in the [mongoimport docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#synopsis) that you should run it outside of the mongo shell.

Answer (score 0):

the `--jsonArray` option on the mongoimport command  is the inverse of the `--jsonArray` on the mongoexport command.

If I insert your example data into a collection and then use `mongoexport --jsonArray` I get the following output.

```
12:12 $ mongoexport --jsonArray --db=jsonarray --collection=array
2019-11-06T12:13:09.155+0000    connected to: localhost
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5dc2b84e785cad8404bd93d8"},"key1-1":"val1-1","key2-1":"val2-1"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5dc2b864785cad8404bd93d9"},"key1-2":"val1-2","key2-2":"val2-2"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5dc2b877785cad8404bd93da"},"key1-3":"val1-3","key2-3":"val2-3"}]
```

To work your input will need an opening and closing square bracket and a comma after each document.